# Image picker status bar issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode5, uiimagepickercontroller

[image: my status bar appearance before picking an image]

Iam using status bar in my application and i wriiten the code in the following manner

[image: my status bar position after picking image]

My project includes tab bar controller. So, after picking an image from library my status bar is changing its postion. How can it solved?

please Anybody help on this I wasted Lot of time With this.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
    self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0,self.window.frame.size.width-20,self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    } else
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got this resolved?

Comment: no, iam trying to get the images in a subview(collectionview) from the Library, bcz presentmodel navigation disturbing my application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The key in `info.plist` file :

```
'View controller-based status bar appearance' and set to NO.
```

Also in appDelegate.

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];  // change style as per your requirement
```

Comment: Generally it is right what u said, but the thing is different here bcz iam using tabbar controller with navigation bar,so i need to update the frame of tab bar & navigation bar. can u help on this?

Comment: Then you can do the same with tabbarcontroller.view.frame and for each viewcontroller - viewcontroller.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.frame

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 and above the status bar is transparent so the best way of achieving this is to make a base controller and extend every controller from it and in `viewDidLoad` of base controller just create a singleton object of that view (i.e. black view) with frame `CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)` with auto resizing mask with width and add it as a subview.

Comment: Yes I written that code in Appdelagate.m file & by using its singleton object i done what u said but Iam not using Autolayout Concept.

Comment: I am not talking about autolayout I am talking about autoresizing mask

Comment: @RakeshKumar don't resize the window as it is a container for all the view controllers.

Comment: @ Adeel Ur Rehman, Thanks for taking me in to new concept, iam not aware of this Concept, do u have an example for that

Comment: @RakeshKumar I described in my answer. Please let me know if you find any confusion in that.

Comment: @ Adeel Ur Rehman,in your answer u mentioned auto resizing mask with width, What does that mean?

Answer (score -1):

```
(void)layoutSubviews {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64);
}
```

Comment: what frame it is??(frame related to view Or window or navigation bar)